# What should be my diet and exercise as I am all skinny and having only belly fat?

Tags: exercise, weight-loss

I am 22 yrs old with a weight of 45 kg and a height of 5'2". I am skinny, but I have belly fat. How can I best fix that with diet and exercise?

Comment: Voted to leave open, as the two questions are definitely not duplicates. This poster has a BMI of 18, and so attempting to lose fat is the last thing they should be doing.

Comment: Voting to reopen, as directing an underweight person to answering instructing them on how to lose further weight is reckless. This question is distinct from the linked "duplicate" questions in that the person asking should definitely not be trying to lose weight.

Comment: @DavidScarlett - I think you may be right that the duplicates are a bit off, but you can suggest better duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

For your nutrition, eat at a caloric maintenance every day (which can be estimated with a TDEE Calculator), the goal of which is for the number on the scale to stay the same. For your training, exercise your entire body and do your sets to or close to failure to ensure that your muscles are being challenged, this is to ensure that they grow as a result. The result of these simple directions is that your body fat percentage will decrease while your muscles become more notable and toned.

If by any chance you are worried about getting too bulky from exercise, don’t be. It takes quite a bit of time to add muscle to the body. If at any point you feel like your muscles are too big, you can easily relax your training. As a more tangible example of what I mean, a man might expect to gain 1-2 lbs of muscle at best over the course of a month, while a woman might expect half of that. Also, you’ll want to be following a competent workout plan that is in line with your goals, not having a plan is a really bad idea and you’ll progress much slower.